# Stuck in an endless loop figuring out why my code wont work

Tags: c++

Trying to retrieve information from another header through function pointers that would pick up the current information the user enters through cin but the problem is that it keeps giving me an 'unitialized error' output everytime I run it but I do not see any problem with this code at all?

This is the current code im catching all the information too

```
#ifndef MANAGEMENT_H
#define MANAGEMENT_H

#include "Customer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Management : public Customer
{
private:
    std::vector<std::string> Cars;
    std::vector<std::string> Customer_Names;
    std::vector<std::string> Customer_Adresses;
    std::vector<unsigned int> Customer_Ages;
public:
    void Order_Complete();
    void Display_Av_Cars();

    bool Get_Customer_Names(std::string* name, std::string* adress, unsigned int* age)
    {
        Customer_Names.push_back(*name);
        Customer_Adresses.push_back(*adress);
        Customer_Ages.push_back(*age);
        return true;
    }

    Management();
};

#endif
```

Which will then be passed down to:

```
void Management::Order_Complete()
{
    Book_Car();
    Get_Customer_Names(&customer_Name, &customer_Adress, &customer_Age);
    std::cout << 
        "Name: " << Customer_Names[0] << '\n' <<
        "Age: " << Customer_Ages[0] << '\n' <<
        "Adress: " << Customer_Adresses[0] << '\n';
}
```

inside Management.cpp
The information I want everything to come from is here:

```
#pragma once

#include "Management.h"

class Customer
{
private:
    Management manage = Management();
protected:
    std::string customer_Name;
    std::string customer_Adress;
    unsigned int customer_Age;
public:
    void Book_Car();

    Customer();
    ~Customer();
};
```

which the user inputs the car they want to order and their details about themselves inside the `void Book_Car();` function

```
void Customer::Book_Car()
{
    std::cout << "Choose car to book: \n";
    manage.Display_Av_Cars();
    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, customer_Name);
    std::cout << "Enter your Adress: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, customer_Adress);
    std::cout << "Enter your age: ";
    std::cin >> customer_Age;
}
```

Why wont this work? I have even tried to initialize all three variables inside `Customer.h` with no success and still keeps giving me the same error:

```
std::string customer_Name = "";
std::string customer_Adress = "";
unsigned int customer_Age = 0;
```

any ideas?

Edit:
Here all the error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   8   
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   10  
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   11  
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   8   
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   10  
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   11  
Error   C2039   'string': is not a member of 'std'  Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   10  
Error   C2039   'string': is not a member of 'std'  Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   11  
Error   C2039   'string': is not a member of 'std'  Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   10  
Error   C2039   'string': is not a member of 'std'  Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   11  
Error   C3646   'manage': unknown override specifier    Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   8   
Error   C3646   'manage': unknown override specifier    Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   8   
Error   C3646   'customer_Name': unknown override specifier Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   10  
Error   C3646   'customer_Name': unknown override specifier Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   10  
Error   C2065   'customer_Name': undeclared identifier  Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Management.cpp   16  
Error   C3646   'customer_Adress': unknown override specifier   Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   11  
Error   C3646   'customer_Adress': unknown override specifier   Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Customer.h   11  
Error   C2065   'customer_Adress': undeclared identifier    Training    C:\Users\Dator\Desktop\C++\C++ Advanced Files\Training\Management.cpp   16  
Error   C2504   'Customer': base class undefined    Training
```

Comment: What is 'unitialized error'?  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69802338/edit) your question to include the *full* error message.

Comment: Off topic: This design looks weird to me; Why is `Management` a `Customer`?  Why does `Management` hold multiple `std::vector`s of customer names, addresses, and ages instead of a `std::vector<Customer>`?  Why does a `Customer` own a `Management`?

Comment: Looks a bit weird to me to now that you mention it. Any ideas to improve the layout?

Comment: I just put in all the errors I'm getting

Comment: You need to sit down and figure out how everything is related. Sometimes drawing pictures helps. Once you've figured out a logical relationship between management and customer, the rest should sort itself out in the wash.

Comment: you have cyclic includes. consider making `Management` not derive from  `Customer`.